# How do you access form values sent using the document.forms["formName"].submit() method?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, submit

I have a table in a php document. It has a button with calls a function in an external javascript file, which calculates values and returns them to the table using `document.formName.varName.value=jsVarName;` 
and then calls the

```
document.forms["formName"].submit()
```

method which should then send the new values to the same php page using

```
(form name="formName" action="pageName.php" method="post")
```

at which point I expected to be able to use

```
if(isset("submit")){ $phpVar=$_POST["tableVarName"];
```

to then access the newly calculated values. Unfortunately, when I try this, there appears to be nothing in the $_POST variables. Do you have any idea where I'm going wrong? I can post code snippets if that would help.

Comment: Why would the string `"submit"` be set ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get anything with $_REQUEST or $_GET? Maybe your form is not being submitted as post. Just a guess!

Comment: yes, I've tried those two. To be honest, I'm not even certain it's submitting the form at all. Am I using a bad submit method? I just don't want to use a submit button because I want to be sure the javascript function is called BEFORE the values are sent.